# Using variables defined within one set builder notation within another?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For example, if I wanted something to express "the set of all pairs of distinct natural numbers", obviously I could do it inside a single set builder notation, but what if I wanted to express it as a cartesian product? Could I do:

$\{x \mid x \in \mathbb{N}\} \times \{y \mid y \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{x\}\}$

Is this allowed, or is $x$ "out of scope" in the second set builder notation? Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $x$ is indeed out of scope.

You can say
$$
\{ \{x,y\} \ | \ x \ne y \} .
$$

If you can carry through your argument with just the words you used to describe that set then I would recommend against the more formal set builder notation.

Words are almost always easier on your reader.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I totally agree here that what you gave is the best solution, and was mostly asking the question to clarify some syntax and rules. Would this, work, however?

$\bigcup_{x \in N} \{x\} \times \{y \mid y \in N \setminus \{x\}\}$

Comment: @EachOneChew Yes, I think so, as long as you put in parentheses after the union to make sure the cross binds first.